# Unit tests Angular + Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Sorry for broken English - the Google translator. I know that the unit tests you can do with karma. But is it possible to do only protractor? Without karma?

Comment: In fact, it is not recommended to use both :)

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I would like to see a link where it is not recommended. Last time I read blog from angular team member http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html, he advised to use both.

Comment: So take a look: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/9#issuecomment-19927049
My point is about the effort to get them working together...

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I see- you meant:
"it is not recommended to use them both for UNIT testing"

Comment: @Capaj Yes ;). But it is the question's headline, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible-you could use https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-webdriver-webdriver-prototype-executescript to load up Jasmine(or other testing framework) and your unit tests in the browser instance, then run them, but it is highly unadvisable. You would be recreating Karma with Protractor.

Keep protractor just for E2E tests and Karma for unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I use Karma to do unit testing and Protractor to do E2E testing.
You could use either, or both. You can use one without the other.